# sqlite3_open error in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
          public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
          {
              private static String DB_NAME;
              private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.muthu.tamil/databases/";
              private final Context myContext;
              private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

             static
              {
                  DB_NAME = "aathichudi.db";
              }

  public DataBaseHelper(Context paramContext)
  {
    super(paramContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + paramContext.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.myContext = paramContext;
  }

  private boolean checkDataBase()
  {
    return new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME).exists();
  }

  private void copyDataBase()
    throws IOException
  {
    InputStream localInputStream = this.myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
    while (true)
    {
      int i = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte);
      if (i <= 0)
      {
        localFileOutputStream.flush();
        localFileOutputStream.close();
        localInputStream.close();
        return;
      }
      localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
    }
  }




  public void createDataBase()
    throws IOException
  {
    if (checkDataBase())
      new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME).delete();
    getReadableDatabase();
    close();
    try
    {
      copyDataBase();
      return;
    }
    catch (IOException localIOException)
    {
    }
    throw new Error("Error copying database");
  }

  public Cursor getData(String paramString)
  {
    return this.myDataBase.rawQuery(paramString, null);
  }

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase)
  {
  }

  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
  }

  public void openDataBase()
    throws SQLException
  {
    this.myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 1);
  }
```

i write code for db connection in android but i get ERROE like this:

> sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.muthu,tamil/databases/aathichudi.db",
>   &handle, 1, NULL) failed
>   sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.muthu,tamil/databases/aathichudi.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
>    sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
>    sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data//data/data/com.muthu.tamil/files/databases/aathichudi.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
>    Shutting down VM
>    threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.muthu.tamil/com.muthu.tamil.HomeActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file 
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>      Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
>       at com.muthu.tamil.sql.DataBaseHelper.openDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:112)
>       at com.muthu.tamil.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:41)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>       ... 11 more

Comment: Are you trying to copy the database into a file or something??

Comment: i try to copy file info into db

Comment: In the constructor, you set the `DB_PATH` to something with `com.muthu,tamil` which seems to be wrong - please note the comma behind `muthu`. However, you should not use hard-coded absolute paths in your code. Try [`paramContext.getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) instead.

Comment: Can you post the full error log from LogCat

Comment: @cyroxx i try it   paramContext.getPackageName()but i get same erroe

Comment: for basic operation to work Sqliteopenhelper needs to just override onupgrade and oncreate, you have implemented everything other than these two. please check some tutorials related to sqliteopenhelper

Comment: Are you trying this on an emulator?

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk i trying both emulator and device (sony Xperia mini, os 4.0 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.muthu,tamil/databases/aathichudi.db", &handle, 1, NULL)
failed sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

This error is produced only when your database is not created in the emulator or the device. You can check whether your database is created in your IDE DDMS/file_explorer (/data/data/Ur_pkg_name/databases/ur_db_name).

There was a bug reported related to this problem: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=949

I have come across with several solutions/workarounds people came up with including the followings:

If you are using sharedUserId in your Manifest file changing the sharedUserId of an application and re-installing the application could work since it does not have the required ownership to write to the SQLite database.

Editing the manifest file can eliminate the mistake again. Inside the manifest, make sure that you've entered the correct min sdk version. You could make sure your min SDK version is OK by checking manifest file if there is an exclamation indicator across the left column from the code telling me of your mistake.

I hope one of these solutions work for you too.